# Print page containing Javascript

Tags: javascript

I've run into quite a problem.
I have a page (http://centralsirescoop.com/proven-sires/cairnbrae-jaces-elton/index.php) which uses javascript to make the green bars adjust their length according to the data in the table next to it. All good there, but when I go to print the page, the bars don't show.

How do I go about printing a page *with* the javascript rendered?

Thank you.

Comment: Hi JavaScript seems to do nothing

Comment: can you create them on server side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enable the option of **Background Color and Images** in print options which will make those bars to be printed.

By default , it won't print background color and images

Comment: That makes perfect sense! The Javascript was being run, it's just that the background colour wasn't being shown. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Hi When you deactivate JavaScript and reload the page the page looks just as when javascript is not deactivated. So may be it's a css-problem, when you remove temporarily everything except of the content-div? But it is only guessed.

Recommendation one:
print everything on the site not just the div.

Recommendation two:
You can open a new window and put all content of your div into the new window.

```
function openElementPrintWindow(element){
    var strWindowFeatures = "menubar=yes,location=yes,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,status=yes";
    win = open('SIDE-URL','Print Content',strWindowFeatures);
    win.onload = function(){
      win.document.body.innerHTML = element.innerHTML;
      win.print();
    };
}
```

The most important part is that the SIDE-URL must reference on a side where css is appropriate ajusted for the content (div) that the window got (code: win.document.body.innerHTML = ...).

Hope this helps a little bit.